# How to process dictionary of 2d-arrays with River?

Tags: unsupervised-learning, online-learning

I want to perform non-supervised anomaly detection of water quality spectra (2d-array: intensity vs wavelength) using incremental River python library.
As far as I have seen, the input data of an observation is a dictionary of features and associated single values. However, I have 1d or 2d-arrays inside my dictionary.
How can I use River to process such data (example below) ?

```
{
'ABSORPTION': [0.14796926826583667, 0.1131116077044668, ... , 0.03030975611350669, 0.03595333482930276], 
'FLUO-01': [8.917000000000002, 18.811000000000007, ..., 27.019999999999996, 32.57699999999999], 
'FLUO-02': [-13.845000000000006, -8.574000000000005, ..., 17.394000000000002, 15.517999999999999], 
'FLUO-03': [3.0250000000000004, 3.6169999999999995, ..., 0.6060000000000001, 0.5879999999999999], 
'FLUO-04': [22.982585914673443, 22.982585914673443, ..., 22.982585914673443, 22.982585914673443],
'Temperature': 28.7,
'Plankton_count': 489,
}
```